# OPTED_OUT_PHONE_NUMBER_FOR_RECIPIENT error in DocuSign Java SDK

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts, docusignconnect

How we can make sure if recipient has opted out SMS notification in receiving the envelope or reminder sms then not send the SMS in DocuSign JAVA SDK.
Kindly Help

Answer (score 0):

This error means that this phone number did not agree to receive SMS messages from DocuSign, you cannot override this from your code or using DocuSign APIs, only the person that has the phone with this number can do this.

https://support.docusign.com/s/articles/sms-service?language=en_US&rsc_301

Explains this, but this is what they have to do, they have to text "START" to DocuSign (the exact phone number to text to depends on the country) and that will enable SMS messages from DocuSign for them moving forward.

Comment: Thanks Gazit for your response.  Is there any other way to handle this error and set Email only delivery for such customers who has opted out SMS? One way is to catch the exception and set delivery method to Email only.

Comment: If you have their email address, you can always deliver to both email and SMS together, and if SMS fails - email is used, you can also catch this error and then modify the envelope to include email for that recipient

Comment: Thanks Inbar. I think this is only one approach to achieve this. I was looking if is there any API available to check weather the phone is opted out the DocuSign SMS or not. Thanks for your response.

Comment: No API like this, but there's a specific error message you can relay on.